# Numerical Solution of pde with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying, without success, to solve numerically the pde $\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial t^2}$ with the boundary conditions $u(0,t)=0$, $u(1,t)=0$, $u(x,0)=0$ and $\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}|_{t=0}=2 \sin(\pi x) + 4 \sin(3 \pi x)$

Here is my code:

```
NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], x, x] == D[ u[x, t], t, t], 
  Derivative[0, 1][u[x, t]][x, 0] == 
   2 Sin[\[Pi] x] + 4 Sin[3 \[Pi] x], u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0, 
  u[x, 0] == 0}, u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

I'have an analytical solution but need the numeric computation for comparison purposes.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], x, x] == D[u[x, t], t, t], 
  Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 2 Sin[π x] + 4 Sin[3 π x], 
  u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == 0}, 
 u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Or

```
NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], x, x] == 
   D[u[x, t], t, t], (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 
   2 Sin[π x] + 4 Sin[3 π x], u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0, 
  u[x, 0] == 0}, u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: That was it, Thanks!